# Change a TextView to an ImageView

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, textview, imageview, settext

In a Drag & Drop Activity,

I want to Drag an image and drop it over a TextView.
And want to change the text view to the image view, that I have dropped.

```
 case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            //This is the textView of the Traget
            TextView dropTarget = (TextView) dragView;

            //Possibly now the View would be an image View now,
            //view being dragged and dropped
            ImageView dropped = (ImageView) view;

            //Now here I want to set the textView of dropTarget as the ImageView of dropped, THIS I WANT TO UNDERSTAND TO HOW TO DO THIS
            dropTarget.setAnimation(dropped.getDrawable());


            break;
```

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will use TextView and set background to textview this will help to you.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i am not able to set the image being dragged as the '.setbackgroud', as it takes into its parameters a backgorund or Rsid